# I/flutter (26976): type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter

I was trying to get total price. My scenario is this :

I have 2 pages involved in this case (i guess, because the error stated to one of this page that related to each other). In my menuUser.dart, I put the icon (just like shopping cart, but not because I am not doing ecommerce project) in this dart file because i already put default tab. So, i just put the icon beside the logout icon.

So, when I click the icon, supposed to be it goes to the next page which are product cart page (AttractionCalc.dart) to update the quantity and get total price (same like ecommerce apps).

My problem is, when I run the application, and when I click at the icon, I get this error in my terminal:

```
I/flutter (26976): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (26976): The following _TypeError was thrown building AttractionCalc(dirty, state:
I/flutter (26976): _AttractionCalcState#57db7):
I/flutter (26976): type 'bool' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'
I/flutter (26976):
I/flutter (26976): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (26976):   AttractionCalc file:///C:/myapp/lib/screen/menuUser.dart:97:59
I/flutter (26976): 
I/flutter (26976): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (26976): #0      _AttractionCalcState.build (package:myapp/view/attractionCalc.dart:172:31)
I/flutter (26976): #1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4619:28)
I/flutter (26976): #2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4502:15)
I/flutter (26976): #3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4675:11)
I/flutter (26976): #4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4218:5)
I/flutter (26976): #5      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2627:33)
I/flutter (26976): #6      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:20)
I/flutter (26976): #7      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
I/flutter (26976): #8      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
I/flutter (26976): #9      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
I/flutter (26976): #10     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
I/flutter (26976): #14     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
I/flutter (26976): #15     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
I/flutter (26976): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (26976):
I/flutter (26976): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

This is my code for menuUser.dart :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myapp/model/api.dart';
import 'package:myapp/network/network.dart';
import 'package:myapp/view/attractionCalc.dart';
import 'package:myapp/view/home.dart';
import 'package:myapp/view/budget.dart';
import 'package:myapp/view/locationMap.dart';
import 'package:myapp/view/profile.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


class MenuUsers extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback signOut;
  MenuUsers(this.signOut);
  @override
  _MenuUsersState createState() => _MenuUsersState();
}


class _MenuUsersState extends State<MenuUsers> {
  
  signOut(){
    setState((){
      widget.signOut();
    });
  }

  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  String deviceID;

  getDeviceInfo()async{
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    print("Device Info : ${androidInfo.id}");
    setState(() {
      deviceID = androidInfo.id;
    });
  }


  String name = "";
  TabController tabController;

  getPref()async{
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      name = preferences.getString("name");
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getPref();
  }

  // total prices
  var loadingTotalPrice = false;
  var totalCart = "0";
  getTotalPrice() async {
    setState(() {
      loadingTotalPrice = true;
    });
    final response = await http.get(NetworkUrl.getTotalPrice(deviceID));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body)[0];
      String total = data['total'];
      setState(() {
        loadingTotalPrice = false;
        totalCart = total;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        loadingTotalPrice = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("TravB", 
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AttractionCalc()));
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.note_add),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: (){
                signOut();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Home(),
            Budget(),
            LocationMap(),
            Profile(),
          ],
          ),
        bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.pink,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
          indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              style: BorderStyle.none
            )
          ),
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              text: "Home",
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.view_list),
              text: "Wishlist",
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.map),
              text: "Location",
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              text: "Profile",
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is my code for AttractionCalc.dart :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:device_info/device_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myapp/model/attractionCalcModel.dart';
import 'package:myapp/network/network.dart';

class AttractionCalc extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AttractionCalcState createState() => _AttractionCalcState();
}

class _AttractionCalcState extends State<AttractionCalc> {
  List<AttractionCalcModel> list = [];

  DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();

  getDeviceInfo()async{
    AndroidDeviceInfo androidInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    print("Device Info : ${androidInfo.id}");
    setState(() {
      unikID = androidInfo.id;
    });
    _fetchData();
  }

  String unikID;

  var loading = false;
  var cekData = false;

  _fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    list.clear();
    final response = await http.get(NetworkUrl.getProductCalc(unikID));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (response.contentLength == 2) {
        setState(() {
          loading = false;
          cekData = false;
        });
      } else {
        final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        setState(() {
          for (Map i in data ) {
            list.add(AttractionCalcModel.fromJson(i));
          }
          loading = false;
          cekData = true;
        });
        getSummaryAmount();
      }
      
    } else {
      setState(() {
          loading = false;
          cekData = false;
      });
    }
  }

  var totalPrice = "0";
  getSummaryAmount() async {
    setState(() {
      loading = true;
    });
    final response = await http.get(NetworkUrl.getSummaryAmountCalc(unikID));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body)[0];
      String total = data['total'];
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
        totalPrice = total;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        loading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  
  _addQuantity(AttractionCalcModel model, String tipe) async {
    await http.post(NetworkUrl.updateQuantity(), body: {
      "idAttraction" : model.id,
      "unikID" : unikID,
      "tipe" : tipe,
      });
    _fetchData();
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getDeviceInfo();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Calculate Attraction Prices"),
        elevation: 1,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: loading ? Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ) 
        : cekData 
        ? Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (context, i){
                  final a = list[i];
                  return Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(a.attractionName),
                              Text("Price : RM ${a.price}"),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 2
                                ),
                                child: Divider(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                )
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              _addQuantity(a, "tambah");
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text("${a.qty}"),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: IconButton(
                            onPressed: (){
                              _addQuantity(a, "kurang");
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            totalPrice == "0" ?? SizedBox(),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
              child: Text("Total Budget : RM ${totalPrice.toString()}"),
            )
          ],
        )
         : Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("You don't have any places to be calculate", 
            textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            ),)
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please let me know where did I went wrong, I am new to Flutter. This is my final year project and I really need some help.

Comment: You are getting this error because of your `totalPrice == "0" ?? SizedBox(),` You can use a ternary like you have been doing. `totalPrice == "0" ?SizedBox() :  Container( padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),child: Text("Total Budget : RM ${totalPrice.toString()}"),)`

Comment: OMG!! thank you very much!!! it's work!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because of your `totalPrice == "0" ?? SizedBox()`.

You can use a `ternary operator` for `if checks` like you have been doing.

See code example below:

```
totalPrice == "0" ? SizedBox() :  Container( padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),child: Text("Total Budget : RM ${totalPrice.toString()}"),)
```